# Can I update items in array with $function operator and index number?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have an object like this, and I'm working with "todos" array, only want update active status with specific indexs are given:

```
{
    "_id": "61e7e78372d3221d2c5fb242",
    "from_date": "2022/01/01 00:00:00",
    "to_date": "2022/01/01 00:00:00",
    "todos": [
        {
            "name": "sub1",
            "desc": "desc1",
            "active": true,
            "owner": "61e6125db0f102060951aa53"
        }, // index = 0
        {
            "name": "sub2",
            "desc": "desc2",
            "active": true,
            "owner": "61e6125db0f102060951aa53"
        }, // index = 1
        ...
    ]
}
```

The first I try update with: ['$set' => ['todos.0.active' => false]]

```
{
    "0": {
        "active": false
    },
    "name": "sub1",
    "desc": "desc1",
    "active": true,
    "owner": "61e6125db0f102060951aa53"
},
```

active can be update to false, key 0 is generated. I continue try other:

```
array_push($pipeline, ['$set' => ['todos' => [
        '$function' => [
            'body' => 'function(todos) {
                return todos; // or do something
            }',
            'args' => ['todos'],
            'lang' => 'js',
        ]
]]]);
```

But todos field turn into string is "todos", not array. What wrong with $set and $function? And other operators can do the same easier like $map or $filter?
My full pipeline update:

```
[
    {
        "$set": {
            "name": "First Task 1",
            "desc": "This is description",
            "status": "completed",
            "done": 100,
            "level": "medium",
            "company": "BBB",
            "project": "AAA",
            "from_date": "2022/01/01 00:00:00",
            "to_date": "2022/01/01 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "$$NOW"
        }
    },
    {
        "$set": {
            "todos.1.active": false
        }
    },
    {
        "$set": {
            "todos": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                    "$todos",
                    [
                        {
                            "name": "sub3",
                            "desc": "desc3",
                            "active": true,
                            "owner": "61e6125db0f102060951aa53"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

db.collection.updateOne(['_id' => ObjectId('')], $pipeline, ['multi' => true]})

I want to update with pipeline, not each single query.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "61e7e78372d3221d2c5fb242"
},
{
  $set: {
    "todos.$[elem].active": false
  }
},
{
  "multi": true,
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "elem.name": {
        $eq: "sub1"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vn2EPYTdFXH)

---

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "61e7e78372d3221d2c5fb242"
},
{
  $set: {
    "todos.0.active": false,
    "todos.2.active": false
  }
},
{
  "multi": true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n9hoW8mjwVI)

---

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "61e7e78372d3221d2c5fb242"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      todos: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $range: [ 0, { $size: "$todos" } ]
          },
          as: "i",
          in: {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                "item": { $arrayElemAt: [ "$todos", "$$i" ] }
              },
              in: {
                $cond: {
                  if: {
                    $in: [ "$$i", [ 0, 2 ] ]
                  },
                  then: {
                    "name": "$$item.name",
                    "desc": "$$item.desc",
                    "active": false,
                    "owner": "$$item.owner"
                  },
                  else: "$$item"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k-bvRyiiWAF)

Comment: first and second demo are working with single query, but with pipeline they dont work. See my update. Do you think I can update "todos" with pipeline like that?

Comment: @May'Habit Looks like my third answer is the only way